# How to change color of navigation content in android

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I want to change color of navigation drawer menu content.when a particular tab is selected.I have shown in image below color onto the navigation drawer content.I want to make red color as a text color of a particular tab when it get selected.

This is xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

drawable/navigation_text_color :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
    <item android:color="#009688" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- This is the default text color -->
    <item android:color="#E91E63" />
</selector>
```

and layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       .
       .
       app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_text_color"/>
```

Comment: If you want to changed the icon color also then use     app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_text_color"